# Handling click on EditText's rightDrawable image

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm implementing a custom search bar in my Android application. This search bar is just an EditText with a magnifier set to leftDrawable property. My problem is that I don't know how to get noticed when the user clicks the magnifier. Is there any listener for doing this? Am I using the recommended approach to implement this search bar? I know I could use an EditText and an ImageButton on its right side, but I want the magnifier to be inside the EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any listener for doing this?

Not specifically for that image.

> Am I using the recommended approach to implement this search bar?

I am not aware that there are recommendations for implementing a search bar. It is not the way Google elected to implement a clickable button for their search bar, which has the button to the right of the field.

You may be able to have the desired effect by:

1. Putting the `EditText` in a `RelativeLayout`
2. Adding a transparent `View` as a later child of the `EditText`, sized to match the size of your image
3. Using margins to have the transparent `View` be over top of your image
4. Setting an `OnClickListener` on the transparent `View`

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to use this approach. =)